# Sort by subset of a Perl string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a hash. The hash key is a long string, "str_3432_123_A12_C02_xy_ut", and I want to sort the keys by a subset of the string which will have the format A12_C02.

I assume no other part of the string will match the regex, but the location inside the string can differ.

```
 [A-Za-z][0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z][0-9]{2}
```

To sort my hash by keys:

```
  my @sorted = sort keys %myhash;
```

I also have a separate array for all the values that could possibly match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `map` and `sort` to extract the part of the string you want to use to sort and recover the whole key once done, like:

```
my @sorted = 
    map { $_->[0] } 
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } 
    map { m/([A-Za-z][0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z][0-9]{2})/ && [$_, $1] } 
    keys %myhash;
```

Comment: this is a late request but can you explain how the first and second map work?

Comment: @Jabda: The first map (starting from the bottom) extracts the substring that will be used to sort keys. It returns an arrayref with both values to use later. The second one is used in the following `sort` and the first one is extracted in the second `map`.

Answer (score 4):

At least if it's not a huge sort, a trivial solution would be to use `sort` directly:

```
my $re = /([a-z][0-9]{2}_[a-z][0-9]{2})/i;
my @sorted = sort {
        ($a) = $a =~ $re;
        ($b) = $b =~ $re;
        $a cmp $b;
    }
    keys %hash;
```