# Perl: sort a hash by value, then by key

Tags: perl

Similar to this question: *[Sort by subset of a Perl string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659499/sort-by-subset-of-a-perl-string)*

I would like to sort first by value, and then by subset of the key.

My `%hash`:

```
 cat_02 => 0
 cat_04 => 1
 cat_03 => 0
 cat_01 => 3
```

The output (could be an array of the keys in this order):

```
cat_02 => 0
cat_03 => 0
cat_04 => 1
cat_01 => 3
```

Bonus: The key secondary comparison would recognize 1234_2_C01 and being smaller than 1234_34_C01 ([cmp](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#sort-LIST) does not).

Comment: `2_` is smaller than `34` both numerically and stringwise so that's a bad example. But I know what you meant. updated my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
my %hash = (
  cat_02 => 0,
  cat_04 => 1,
  cat_03 => 0,
  cat_01 => 3
);

print "$_ => $hash{$_}\n"
  for sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} or $a cmp $b } keys %hash;
```

The sort does numeric comparison of the values, and if they're equal, the part after the `or` is executed, which does string comparison of the keys. This gives the output you asked for.

For smart sorting of strings that contain numbers mixed with non-numeric stuff, grab the alphanum comparison function from *[The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)* and replace `$a cmp $b` with `alphanum($a,$b)`.

Comment: whats the affect of cmp on numbers in strings vs letters, say instead of cat you had as keys 1234_2_C01_HT1  and 1234_23_C01_HT2 .

Comment: @Jabda, `cmp` compares in lexicographical order, i.e. `12 cmp 2` will produce `-1`, while `12 <=> 2` will produce `1`. As a special case, if number of figures in both numbers are the same `cmp` and `<=>` will produce same results.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a secondary sort preference, you simply add another level inside the sort routine:

```
my %hash = (
    cat_02 => 0,
    cat_04 => 1,
    cat_03 => 0,
    cat_01 => 3
);

my @sorted = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} || $a cmp $b } keys %hash;
                  #  primary sort method    ^^ secondary sort method
for (@sorted) {
    print "$_\t=> $hash{$_}\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
cat_02  => 0
cat_03  => 0
cat_04  => 1
cat_01  => 3
```

Comment: There is no "levels", "primary sort methods" or "secondary sort methods" it is just boolean expression which compares values first and if they are equal compares keys. I mean, currently explanation looks like "this is some magic syntax for sorting by `x` then by `y`".

Comment: Sure there's sorting methods, and one of them is primary, the other is secondary, from a priority point of view. Its not magical, no, as is plainly visible in the code, its just using the logical OR operator.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done (quickly!) using the Sort::Key:: modules:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( );
use Sort::Key::Maker intnatkeysort => qw( integer natural );

my @sorted_keys = intnatkeysort { $hash{$_}, $_ } keys(%hash);
```

Or you can take advantage of the properties of your data and just use a natural sort:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natkeysort );

my @sorted_keys = natkeysort { "$hash{$_}-$_" } keys(%hash);
```

- [Sort::Key::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aNatural)
- [Sort::Key::Maker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aMaker)

Answer (score 1):

It may be not worth it in this particular case, but [**Schwartzian transform**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) technique can be used with multi-criteria sort too. Like this ([codepad](http://codepad.org/FWsfVQA1)):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %myhash = (
  cat_2 => 0, cat_04 => 1,
  cat_03 => 0, dog_02 => 3, 
  cat_10 => 0, cat_01 => 3,
);

my @sorted = 
    map { [$_->[0], $myhash{$_->[0]}] } 
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]  or  $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } 
    map { m/([0-9]+)$/ && [$_, $myhash{$_}, $1] } 
    keys %myhash;

print $_->[0] . ' => ' . $_->[1] . "\n" for @sorted;
```

Obviously, the key to this technique is using more than one additional element in the cache.

Two things here: 1) `@sorted` actually becomes array of arrays (each element of this array is key-value pair); 2) sorting in this example is based on keys' digits suffix (with numeric, not string comparison), but it can be adjusted in any direction if needed.

For example, when keys match pattern XXX_DD_XXX (and it's DD that should be compared), change the second `map` clause with this:

```
    map { m/_([0-9]+)_/ && [$_, $myhash{$_}, $1] }
```